# How do I use this bandpass filter?

Tags: matlab, filters, convolution, bandpass, embedded-systems

I found this free DSP book by Rutgers University professor Sophocles J. Orfanidis. The book is called [Introduction to Signal Processing](http://eceweb1.rutgers.edu/%7Eorfanidi/intro2sp/) and the link contains many different implementations of common DSP functions in both MATLAB and C.

My intention is to eventually implement this [Butterworth BPF](http://eceweb1.rutgers.edu/%7Eorfanidi/intro2sp/mdir/bpsbutt.m) in C for an embedded platform. The BPF is described in section 11.6.4 [on page 618 of the PDF version of this book](http://eceweb1.rutgers.edu/%7Eorfanidi/intro2sp/orfanidis-i2sp.pdf).

On page 622 there is a filter design example 11.6.5 which shows how to obtain the BPF coefficients. As I understand it, these coefficients are for the four stages of a cascaded filter design,  $H_0(z), H_1(z), H_2(z), H_3(z)$ as described on page 621 and the overall transfer function is
$H(z) = H_0(z)H_1(z)H_2(z)H_3(z)$

I do not understand how to use the output of `bpsbutt.m` to create $H(z)$ and $h(n)$

My goal is to generate band-limited noise on an embedded platform in real time. I want to do this by generating AWGN and filtering it with a BPF. Platform i am using is an RFSoC with an ARM processor.

The center frequency must be adjustable across a range from 500 MHz to 2000 MHz with a minimum center frequency step of 1 MHz and a maximum of 50 MHz.

The bandwidth of the noise must be adjustable from 100 MHz to 300 MHz.

My question is this: Could you please provide a MATLAB example of how to properly use this function to filter a signal?

Comment: Hi! You're asking for matlab code, written to your specification! That's explicitly off-topic here. Instead, try to explain the signal processing problem (not the programming problem) that you're trying to solve – why not simply use matlab's own filter design methods? also: are you *sure* you want to do a butterworth on an embedded device? Filter designs lifted from the analog domain to the discrete-time domain are rarely the optimal choice.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I am not sure and thats why im asking questions here. What do you suggest as an alternative? The problem i am trying to solve is to generate band limited noise and my approach is to generate AWGN then filter with a BPF to get band-limited noise. I need the BPF to be tunable and to be able to operate across a frequency range

Comment: then: don't use a variable bandpass filter (which is really annoying to re-design on the fly, especially on a small computer), but a fixed-bandwidth low-pass filter. Multiply its output with a cosine (or a complex sinusoid, if this is complex baseband) to shift the center frequency from 0 to the desired frequency.

Comment: I need to be able to adjust the width of the passband of the filter as well not just the center frequency. Generating coefficients is not a problem with the embedded device i am using. It has more than enough resources to be able to do this.

Comment: ah, then you'd still do an adjustable low-pass filter, and shift its output :) May I ask for what you need the band-limited  noise, and in which steps you need to adjust bandwidth and center frequency? Could you please edit your question to include that info, it might be very relevant to answerers!

Comment: Any literature for how to go about implementing the LPF approach? It's just one of the waveforms i need to create for a project im working on. I edited the question and added the information you suggested.

Comment: OK; the bandwidths are **impressive**. Certainly not something you can do on an embedded processor! This is really confusing; to fulfill your requirements, your system needs to have a throughput of more than 4 Gigasamples a second, and I can't do that with a 32 core server, so, honestly, I think you might be solving a problem that is not your actual problem. Even if your software only needs to generate 300 MHz of bandwidth, that's 600 Megasamples per second, and that's beyond PC-style hardware, and clearly beyond embedded computing. Your whole requirements do not add up!

Comment: notice how matlab *definitely* isn't up to the task of even doing 50 Megasamples per second in filtering of a benign Butterworth complexity, so, again, something is totally amiss and you'll need to describe your system and application! My guess is you want to do this on an FPGA SoC – maybe an AMD/Xilinx RFSoC? – and you want to generate the filter coefficients on the ARM, to load them into a filter core on the FPGA. Then, stick to an FIR design, which probably lends itself much better to this kind of problem, as it allows for nicer parallelization.

Comment: It is an RFSoC platform. I generate samples using the ARM, stick them into the block RAM of the RFSoC and play them out. Should be doable even though the requirements are tough. FIR filter is a good idea, i agree. Any suggestions for where i can find good literature for generating the coefficients?

Comment: makes no sense – or did Mathwork port Matlab to ARM? you want a standard textbook on filter design (which is honestly more of a 1970s to 1980s topic, because afterwards, the optimizers took over, and these days the average engineer who just wants a specific shape will just define the desired shape, and run python/matlab/… functionality to find the optimal coefficients given the shape, error weights and length constraints)

Comment: you can totally forget about creating four billion samples of white noise on the ARM. Does, and will not happen. Source: supervised a FPGA thesis doing gigasample WGN generation on an RFSoC. You're multiple orders of magnitude off in performance from what you need. And I'm talking about hand-assembled highly optimized noise generation, not about matlab.

Comment: also note that the bandwidth between the ARM and the FPGA fabric on the RFSoC will not suffice for > 4GS/s, even if your CPU wasn't bottlenecking. This has to *completely* happen in the FPGA. If you want to see how you can generate 38 GS/s of *Gaussian* white noise on an RFSoC, see https://github.com/Yamakaja/boxmuller ; if you only care about the white noise, not the Gaussianness, complexity reduces, and you only need to use [the XOROSHIRO128+ module](https://github.com/Yamakaja/boxmuller/blob/master/src/xoroshiro128plus.vhd). Do cite David Winter, though, if you do.

Comment: Port MATLAB to ARM? What do you mean? Whatever I'm doing on the ARM is in C not MATLAB. Platform i am working on can provide up to 9.81 GSPS so its definitely doable. It's not a hardware issue its a software issue. Again, im not using the ARM to do anything but math.

Comment: OK; you really need to explain to me how you can produce nearly 10 GS/s of sufficiently white noise on an ARM as anemic as the one on the RFSoC. And how you get that into the programmable logic.

Comment: I use the ARM to do math to generate samples that i put in a certain memory location on the BRAM of the SoC. Then the firmware transmits the samples out of the DAC. An ARM can run a for loop and make computations and thats all i need it to do.

Comment: yes, but if you loop through that RAM, your noise stops being white, but gets perfect autocorrelation – and at the sizes of RAM available, and at your converter rates, at relevant delays!

Comment: its actually not required to be AWGN. Noise samples can be uniformly distributed. I got 2MB of RAM to play with and may be able to increase that number a little.

Comment: um, 2MB of RAM are how many samples? At which rate do you play these back? (hint: far too little samples, far too high rates!)

Comment: it is 1048576 samples at a rate of 4 GHz

Comment: Say, these are 16 bit samples, so you have $2^{20}$ samples, and your sampling rate is 4 GS/s, so ca $2^{32}$ S/s; your signal now inherently has a perfect peak at $2^{32-20}$ Hz, so at 4 kHz; since within a short region, samples are randomly correlated (they're only white on infinite length observation), you also "amplify" observing these frequencies. For us (see link above), that simply was no option, as we were testing high-performance decoders with this, and these periodicities would have invalidated our results.

Comment: Might work for you, but honestly, dealing with this block RAM is harder than producing much better white pseudo-random numbers at demand speed, so that was an easy choice :D

Answer (score 3):

That is one of the more tortured output formats I've seen: It's basically cascaded 4th order sections. For embedded implementation I would recommend converting this into cascaded 2nd order sections. If you want to use this format directly in Matlab you can try something like this:

```
%% Design bandpass from 1kHz to 2kHz, 
fs = 48000; % sample rate
[a,b,p] = bpsbutt(1,fs,1000,2000,1000/sqrt(2),2000*sqrt(2),1,60);
% calcualte the impulse response by cascaded filtering
nx = 2^14; d0 = zeros(nx,1); d0(1) = 1;
h0 = d0;
for i = 1:size(a,1)
  h0 = filter(b(i,:),a(i,:),h0);
end

%% do a quick plot
fh0 = fft(h0);
frAxis = (1:nx/2)'/nx*fs;
semilogx(frAxis,20*log10(abs(fh0(2:nx/2+1))));
xlabel('Freq in Hz ->');
ylabel('Level in dB ->');
grid('on');
set(gca,'ylim',[-100 3]);
```

Comment: thank you for replying! This is really helpful! My goal is to generate band-limited noise on an embedded device and my approach is to create AWGN samples and filter them with a BPF that is tunable and can operate across a frequency range. Could you point me to some literature that would be better suited for this application if you think this is not the best approach?

Comment: Matlab and Python have perfectly good filter design packages build in.

Answer (score 2):

The MATLAB code you have shown just outputs coefficients for IIR butterworth filter, the same can be done with MATLAB's built in `butter` function. It's probably not required that you implement this into embedded unless absolutely necessary. There's plenty of documentation on how to find the coefficients for the type of filter you want (i.e. butterworth) depending on your application:

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html

The only thing useful MATLAB is probably useful for is quickly calculating the coefficients for your filter offline and hard-code them in your embedded code.

The butterworth filter you have shown is an IIR filter as it provides two sets of coefficients `a` and `b`. The [link](http://eceweb1.rutgers.edu/%7Eorfanidi/intro2sp/) you have provided does not have a .c implementation of such filter (only see a FIR.c implementation). You can search online for implementing IIR filters in C ; example here on stack overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588879/how-to-implement-iir-filter-in-c

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know the link doesnt have a C implementation thats why i said i want to implement it in C and yes it is necessary for me. I need to generate the coefficients because the filter needs to be tunable and be able to operate across a frequency band so hard coding coefficients is not something i can do.

Comment: Are you saying you NEED to compute the filter coefficients in real time on embedded hardware? May I ask why?

Comment: Because i need to be able to change my center frequency and bandwidth of operation

Comment: I guess it depends on which embedded processor you intend to do this on - If it's anything like microchip, they have their own library code for applying IIR and FIR filter but no libraries for generating coefficients; other platforms may be more generous.

Comment: its a Xilinx Zynq RFSoC

Comment: There is a FIR compiler IP block for Vivado but I believe the coefficients are hard-coded in. Why not hard-code a range of options of frequency ranges to choose from rather than trying to handle every frequency range?

Comment: Alternatively send the coefficients to the hardware ?

Comment: @pm101 IIRC you can load them, or you can use one or two FFT cores for an overlap-save (or -add? I keep forgetting which was more elegant in this case) FIR implementation.

Comment: i thought about hard coding but it seems to me like it wont work for every case and its clunky because i'd need to hard code a lot of coefficients to cover the range i need. Generating the coefficients seems like the way to go in this case